# End of statement VBA with SAP GUI script

Tags: vba, compiler-errors, sap-gui

I'm doing macro with connection but this syntax error appeared:

> End of Statement

I tried to duplicate the quotation marks but unsuccessfully, another error
appeared.

```
LINHA = 11
Cells(11, 1).Select

Cells(LINHA, 2).Value = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").Text"          2", "&Hierarchy"
```

Comment: VBA is expecting `.Text` to terminate the statement; it doesn't know what to do with the `"          2"", "&Hierarchy"` string that follows. Missing a comma after `.Text`, maybe?

Comment: I just tried , and the same error happen

Comment: `= session.findById("...").Text` is a statement. I've no idea what you mean to do with the rest off the line of code - is that meant to be another parameter to `findById`? In that case it needs to be within the `(...)` parenthesized argument list.

Comment: Hi , It would be a path to a certain part of SAP , ("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").Text"          2", "&Hierarchy" = It is the field in a finished part of the SAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntactically, you have essentially this (depending which revision of the post we're looking at):

```
Object.Property = Object.Method(arguments).Property"some stray string literal", "another string literal"
                                                   ^ end of statement expected here
```

While this is a legal statement:

```
Object.Property = Object.Method(arguments).Property
```

Either remove the stray string literal, or make it part of the arguments to the `findById` method - I don't know the SAP API, but since you're coding against it you should have access to some documentation explaining what the expected arguments are.

This code will compile - again I have no idea what the SAP API wants to see, so it might blow up at run-time, but at least it's legal code:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(LINHA, 2).Value = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]", 2, "&Hierarchy").Text
```

Comment: Hi , i try use your code , but now the error is: "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" .

Comment: Like I said, I don't have an SAP library and I'm not familiar with the SAP API - if that's a compile-time error then the library is referenced and the `session` member call is early-bound - you can re-type the `(` opening parenthesis after `findById` or press Ctrl+i to see what parameter(s) it's expecting, and work with that. Look at the SAP API documentation for `findById` if you're unsure what the argument(s) need to be.